# mailcore2 163.com/126.com NO SELECT The login is not safe

Tags: mailcore2, mailcore

I have the following configuration for mailing features:

```
self.session.clientIdentity.version = @"1.0.0";
self.session.clientIdentity.vendor = @"1ihoo.0";
self.session.clientIdentity.name = @"1mail.0";
self.session.hostname = self.account.imapHost;
self.session.port = self.account.imapPort;
self.session.username = self.account.email;
self.session.password = self.account.password;
```

However, this results in an error:

```
function:__31-[SMImapConnection setAccount:]_block_invoke line:125 content:data: 5 ID (version "1.0.0" name "1mail.0" vendor "1ihoo.0")

function:__31-[SMImapConnection setAccount:]_block_invoke line:125 content:data: 5 BAD Parse command error

function:__31-[SMImapConnection setAccount:]_block_invoke line:125 content:data: 6 SELECT INBOX

function:__31-[SMImapConnection setAccount:]_block_invoke line:125 content:data: 6 NO SELECT The login is not safe! Please update your mail client: http://mail.163.com/dashi
```

I don't think it's wrong, but I don't know why I did it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try select command before ID just like this:

`a1 SELECT INBOX
 a2 ID (version "1.0.0" name "1mail.0" vendor "1ihoo.0")`